# How do i find the cause of memory leaks with Eclipse MAT?

Tags: java, android, heap-dump

[image]

> **Problem Suspect 1**
>
> 17.183 instances of "java.lang.Class", loaded by "" occupy 6.892.312 (33,60%) bytes.
>
> Keywords java.lang.Class
>
> **Problem Suspect 2**
>
> 85.487 instances of "java.lang.String", loaded by "" occupy 5.897.192 (28,75%) bytes.
>
> Keywords java.lang.String

This is my first time analyzing a heap dump so i have no idea how i can fix these problems.

So any tips where i should start looking to find the cause?

Comment: why are you sure that your problem is memory leak?

Comment: @Mr.AF I'm not sure, but what do these problems mean?

Comment: @Mr.AF Eclipse Mat says these 2 problems are leak suspects so i thought these 2 problems are causing a memory leak?

Comment: okay ,  i got yea , so what's your main problem? is there any issue ? UI lag? out of memory ?

Comment: i can generally tell you what's the problem i can't address the problem.

Comment: @Mr.AF My app runs quite smooth to be honest, but i tried leakcanary too check if there were any leaks and it did return a heap dump which i then analyzed with Eclipse Mat because i read somewhere it was easier to pinpoint a leak. But i really have no knowledge of how to handle/fix these problems.

Comment: You have to dump heap for several minutes and put it under test for 10-15 minutes .and make a dump make sure you open all the pages and sections of your app. after doing that analyze the dump by MAT if there are suspected memory leak ?

Comment: make a table and put records like Minutes | Memory Problem size(a) | Memory Problem size (b)

Comment: make a table with at least 10 records and see if there are any increase in memory if you stay long on app

Comment: IF your memory dump increased drastically depend on minutes , DEFINITELY you have memory leak.

Comment: memory leak actually happens increasing in amount by time . step by step consumes memory  .

Comment: Classes loaded by the application or bootstrap loader are never garbage collected in general, so you can't have a leak with `java.lang.Class` instances. Whether you keep a reference or not, they're not going away anyway. Further, it's normal that strings occupy a significant fraction of the heap. And a total heap of 20MB is tiny by today's standards.